# CIFS share sometimes can't mount anymore

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

We have windows share that is accessed from both windows and ubuntu.

For ubuntu I added a mount based on cifs with /etc/fstab

> //dfs/share /mnt/dfs cifs nocase,rw,cred=/etc/cifspasswd 0 0

Most of the time it works well, but every few weeks some directories give question marks for their stats.

```
ls -l /mnt/dfs
```

- drwx--x--x 2 root root 0 Aug 24 17:46 ShippingNote
- d????????? ? ?    ?    ?            ? Target01
- d????????? ? ?    ?    ?            ? Target02

Here Shippingnote is reachable but target0x is not.
We had a theory that the server was unable to get a new kerberos ticket from the domain controller, so we tried restarting sssd and realmd. But this did not help, only a reboot fixes it.  And then it returns after a while.

> lsb_release -a: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

After it happened again we see that also windows accessing the shares has problems

> Create directory \dfs\FE\Backup09\2021-12-04\188424 failed

But they go away after a while and windows can access them again

The ubuntu says the same when trying to mount the share to a docker container

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source
> path '/mnt/dfs/target09/2021-12-04': mkdir /mnt/dfs/target

But the ubuntu never recovers from it.

Only a reboot helps, but what can we do to make it work again without rebooting?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: That is not a version that is a kernel number. A version would be something like Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It seems you are a bit behind in updates. Run sudo apt-get update and after it is complete run sudo apt-get upgrade to make sure all of the system is up to date. No point trying to do anything else till this has been done.